# Define a Static variable, initialize it and then use it in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables, static

I am quite new programming macros in Excel and I am not sure how to initialize a Static variable, initialize it once, and then use it keeping the value when I modify it during different function calls.

I have a cell with the caption "Hide rows", and I want to toggle the visualization of different rows when clicking that cell.

I tried with this code, but like I initialize the variable Hidden to False at the beginning, it only works hidding the rows, not showing them.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Static Hidden As Boolean
  Hidden = False

  If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F8")) Is Nothing Then
        If Hidden = False Then
            Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Hidden = True

            MsgBox "Aaaau!"

            Hidden = True
        Else
            Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Hidden = False

            MsgBox "Hola!"

            Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you set hidden to false at the beginning of the macro, so hidden is always false when entering the test instruction.

try this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Static Hidden As Boolean

  If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F8")) Is Nothing Then
        If Hidden = False Then
            Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Hidden = True

            MsgBox "Aaaau!"

            Hidden = True
        Else
            Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Hidden = False

            MsgBox "Hola!"

            Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```